# How to make an android app to never be closed? (simulate kiosk mode)

Tags: android

I'm developing for GearVR in Unity a 360 video app. The application will be handled by promoters in a mall. Since GearVR can't run in kiosk mode (as far I know, it just launch a warning when i try it). So, **how can i make that the app can't be closed (killed), or if its closed (killed), it auto reopen immediately?** I can export the project from Unity to Android studio (I'm pretty noob with services and that stuffs, so if you can post a code snippet ,id appreciate it).  Cheers

Comment: If this was a possibility think how this could be abused ...

Comment: I think you should look at the screen pinning option. https://support.quicktapsurvey.com/support/solutions/articles/208386-kiosk-mode-android-5-0-lollipop-or-higher

Comment: @MarkKeen is possible, i've seen it in apps from customers. There are third party apps that can do the trick also, but i just want to implement it in my app

Comment: @tyczj Gear VR apps cant be pinned, thats why im asking

Comment: depends what you mean by closed .. if the process is killed .. it is dead ... sure you can have a foreground service opening your app if it is closed, but that is attached to the app process ..

Comment: Plan B  train the promoters.

Comment: @danny117 , the thing is, there are 30 gear vr phones running simultaneously, and handle constantly the devices means they get dirty too fast with fingerprints and dust.

Comment: @MarkKeen there's an app called "surelock" that allows to use a "single app mode", and i can achieve the same result that i want, but i just want to know how to do that programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a background web socket server and have the Android app connect to the server on startup. When/if the app closes the web socket your server restarts it.

Comment: This answer was supposed to be a comment